# Kivy take screenshot with clear background

Tags: python, png, transparency, kivy, alpha

I'm working on a Kivy app that lets the user position images and text labels on a template. When they're done, the resulting image is cropped to fit the template.

I need all the empty space in the image to be clear, as I will be printing the image and don't want to waste ink. Kivy, however, fills all the empty space with black. Is there a way for Kivy's export_to_png() function to use a transparent background instead of a black one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could be wrong, but it looks like the transparent colour is hardcoded.

Looking at the [source code](http://kivy.org/docs/_modules/kivy/uix/widget.html) it seems that `ClearColor` is hard-coded as black.

```
def export_to_png(self, filename, *args):
        '''Saves an image of the widget and its children in png format at the
        specified filename. Works by removing the widget canvas from its
        parent, rendering to an :class:`~kivy.graphics.fbo.Fbo`, and calling
        :meth:`~kivy.graphics.texture.Texture.save`.

        .. note::

            The image includes only this widget and its children. If you want
            to include widgets elsewhere in the tree, you must call
            :meth:`~Widget.export_to_png` from their common parent, or use
            :meth:`~kivy.core.window.WindowBase.screenshot` to capture the whole
            window.

        .. note::

            The image will be saved in png format, you should include the
            extension in your filename.

        .. versionadded:: 1.9.0
        '''

        if self.parent is not None:
            canvas_parent_index = self.parent.canvas.indexof(self.canvas)
            self.parent.canvas.remove(self.canvas)

        fbo = Fbo(size=self.size, with_stencilbuffer=True)

        with fbo:
            ClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1)
            ClearBuffers()
            Scale(1, -1, 1)
            Translate(-self.x, -self.y - self.height, 0)
```

I guess you could try updating the Widget module code to accept a parameter to set the `ClearColor`.

Comment: I modified the function to use the Window.clearcolor for the clear color. This is going to be used in an embedded application, so I'm not terribly worried about cross-platform compatibility.

Comment: Yup, worked a charm. Set the clear color alpha to 0 and the black background went away!